# Can't get the correct parameters from PayPal's new screen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I'm developing an application in rails, my problem is that now with the new design of PayPal's screen, when it redirects the client to my web page to notify him if the transaction has been done correctly, I only get in `[:params]` the controller's and the action's name, when I should receive this two parameters: `[:payment_status]` and `[:payer_status]`.

I'll try to explain it better, sometimes, when the user finishes the checkout on my web page and clicks on the "buy" button, my page redirects him to a PayPal screen that has the description of the products bought in the top of the page, and sometimes to another screen that has the description in the right side of the screen.

After he pays on PayPal, he has the option to return to my page, where he would be notified with a message like "The transaction has been done". The problem is that always that the user is redirected to the second PayPal screen, after he pays and returns to my page, a message like this appears "The transaction could not be finished correctly", because like I said before I don't get the correct parameters. But always that the user is redirected from the first screen, I get the correct parameters and I can show the "transaction completed" message correctly.

Comment: Could you please describe your issue more fully? I am unsure what exactly you're referring to. You say PayPal's screen is the issue, but say the issue is when the customer is redirected to your site: these are two conflicting statements. Why don't you use PDT or IPN?

Comment: I'll try to explain it better, sometimes, when the user finishes the checkout on my web page and clicks on the "buy" button, my page redirects him to a paypal screen that has the description of the products buyed in the top of the page, and sometimes to another screen that has the description in the right side of the screen.

Comment: After he pays on paypal, he has the option to return to my page, where he would be notified with a message like "The transaction has been done".
The problem is that always that the user is redirected to the second paypal's screen, after he pays and returns to my page, appears a message like "The transaction could not be finished correctly", because, like i said before i don't get the correct parameters.
But always that the user is redirected from the first screen, i get the correct parameters and i can show the "transaction completed" message correctly.

Comment: You should edit your initial question to add this information. It sounds like PayPal may have a problem with the classic and Unified checkout pages not returning data correctly. I know you cannot control whether the classic or unified checkout appears, but PayPal is intending to move everything over to the unified checkout eventually.

Comment: What method are you using to return the data? PDT? RM= ?

Comment: Are you setting rm=2 or 1, do you have auto return on, what is the code you're using on your return URL? with PDT, only some of the variables are returned, then you must submit them back to PayPal, along with your PDT token, PayPal then returns all of the transaction variables to you. Are you receiving any data (check both POST and GET) when someone is returned from one checkout rather than the other? Maybe its returning as a POST instead of a GET, or a GET instead of a POST.

Comment: Thank you very much SgtPooky!! I had to set RM to 2 and it worked!